# Создать папки в bash скрипте через консоль

Tags: linux, bash

Подскажите есть проблема с выполнение команды mkdir через скрипт bash.

Если запускаю команду в консоле все работает.

```
mkdir -p /var/work_file/site/catalog/delivery
```

Создаются промежуточная папка "catalog" и в ней "delivery"

Если создаю скрипт и добавлю в него такой код

```
mkdir -p /var/work_file/site/$1
```

И вызываю через консоль

```
./site.sh /catalog/delivery
```

Пробовал и такой вариант вызова

```
./site.sh catalog/delivery
```

Получаю ошибку

```
-bash: ./site.sh: No such file or directory
```

Comment: а попробуйте вызывать `./site.sh catalog/delivery`

Comment: Пробовал в таком формате ./site.sh catalog/delivery, все равно идет ошибка которую написал выше.

Comment: `mkdir -p /var/work_file/site/$1` это весь файл site.sh ?

Comment: а вы точно вызываете из той директории, где находится site.sh файл?

Comment: Да вы правы, я забыл, что перешел в другую директорию и пробую вызывать и нее. Все работает, спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*No such file or directory* говорит о том, что bash не смог найти исполняемый файл. 
Вы, скорее всего, находитесь в доругой директории.

Нужно либо перейти в нужную директорию, где находится файл и выполнить, либо указать полный путь к файлу.